# Оптимизация отрисовки спрайтов и фона

Tags: python, pygame

Возможно ли как то оптимизировать отрисовку да бы не просаживать fps?

Я загружаю в проект фоны(1920х1080) и спрайты(900х1080, в формате png c прозрачным фоном), и подгоняю их под нужные размеры окна через `pg.transform.scale`.

При отрисовке окна в фуллскрин fps падает с 60 до 40, а нагрузка на процесс возрастает до 20%

Я так же проверил... происходит ли постоянное обновление... и нет... нет ничего такого что бы сильно нагружало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину!

Я не совсем понимаю как... но оно так...

Я импортировал изображение спрайта добавив к нему `.convert_alpha()`

Так что бы получилось `self.image = pg.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha()`

И fps перестал скакать, надеюсь это кому-то поможет